# How to refer to a screen of screen manager

Tags: python, kivy

I'm still new to kivy and I can't seem to find my case elsewhere. I want to access the method inside a screen class from the main app class:

```py
class MainGUI(Screen):
    d_travelled = StringProperty()
    def update_distance(self,dt):
         self.d_travelled = dt

class SecondaryGUI(Screen):
    pass

class GUIManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class WindowGUI(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.odrive = myDrive.Motors()
        threading.Thread(target = self.RobotControl).start()

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'MyTitle'
        kv = all_imports.Builder.load_file('kv_styles/robot_3.kv')# which instantiate the GUIs
        return kv
    
    def RobotControl(self):
        while True:
            self.root.update_distance(self.odrive.encoder_cal()) <-----Error
```

I have my robot instruction in `WindowGUI` which needs to run with kivy side by side. For starters, I would like to display the encoder reading on my MainGUI. But `self.root` in `RobotControl` refers to `GUIManager`. Of course this throws an error. How do I refer to `MainGUI` in `RobotControl`? Is it possible to put `def update_distance(self,dt)` in `GUIManager` and have `MainGUI` display the encoder reading? if so, how?

My kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.0
#:import utils kivy.utils
GUIManager:
    MainGUI:
    SecondaryGUI:

<MainGUI>:
    name: "main"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: root.width, root.height #covers entire window
        padding: 15
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            spacing: 10
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            # padding_right: 50
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"horizontal"
                size_hint: 1,.4 

                Label:
                    text: "Drop Distance"
                    size_hint: .75,0.1
                
                Button:
                    id: zero_drop
                    text: "Zero"
                    size_hint: .25,.1
                    on_press:app.odrive.zero_encoder_read()
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                TextInput:
                    id: Encoder
                    multiline: False
                    readonly: True
                    text: root.d_travelled <-------I want to display it here
                    size_hint_x: 0.75
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to el3phanten from kivy discord channel. This is how I solved my problem:

```
from kivy.clock import mainthread

class MainGUI(Screen):
    # Do something

class SecondaryGUI(Screen):
    pass

class GUIManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class WindowGUI(App):
    d_travelled = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.odrive = myDrive.Motors()
        threading.Thread(target = self.RobotControl).start()

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'MyTitle'
        kv = all_imports.Builder.load_file('kv_styles/robot_3.kv')
        return kv
    
    def RobotControl(self):
        while True:
            val = self.odrive.encoder_cal()
            self.set_val(val)

    @mainthread 
    def set_val(self, val) :
    self.d_travelled = val
```

And kv:

```
    BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                TextInput:
                    id: Encoder
                    multiline: False
                    readonly: True
                    text: app.d_travelled 
                    size_hint_x: 0.75
```